# Postgresql role_table_grants grantee differences between users

Tags: postgresql

I have two users [UserA, UserB] -- UserA is an existing user. I just created UserB and gave it `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`.

But when I try to see privileges by doing

`select * from information_schema.role_table_grants`

UserA sees a lot more rows than UserB in the public schema.

For example

1. UserA can see all the rows with `grantee` in "admin_group", but UserB can't.
2. UserA and UserB can see all the rows with `grantee` in "user_group".

This is confusing because I did not do anything special to "user_group" (that I know of). What additional permission do I have to give to UserB so it can see all rows in `information_schema.role_table_grants`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that UserA belongs to "admin_group" and that UserB does not belong to "admin_group".
Please post output of following statements run by a superuser from psql CLI:

```
\du userA
\du userB
select * from information_schema.role_table_grants where grantee='user_group';
select * from information_schema.role_table_grants where grantee='admin_group';
```

Comment: You got it! Thanks. UserA was in a superuser group that had access to all other groups. UserB was not. But this answer confuses me even more. This `role_table_grants` table seems pointless to me. If UserB has access to `GRANT` privileges on a schema to any role, but can't actually see privileges already granted to all roles, then what's the point. This means there could potentially be a ton of duplicate grants because UserB doesn't know about UserA grants.